# Page reloading on pressing enter key in knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have input control for autocomplete inside form tag like below:

```
 <input type="text" class="tags" data-bind="value: selectedMember(), event: { keypress: $root.DisablePostBack}" />
```

I have added blur event for force selection like below:

```
$(function () {
        $('.tags').autocomplete({
            //make ajax call to get all mentored member of logged member
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({

                });
            },
            minlength: 0,
            focus: function () {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                self.selectedMember(this.value);
                return false;
            }

        }).blur(
            function () {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                self.selectedMember(terms);
                return false;
            }
                );
```

blur event will be called when user type name instead of selecting member from autocomplete and pressing enter key.
My problem is when i press enter key, page is reloading again. How to prevent page reloading when pressing enter key.

*EDIT: * To disable enter key i have added one function like below:

```
self.DisablePostBack = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And called it on keypress of that textbox.But after that keys are not working.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is knockout issue. This can be default form behavior. Anyway you have to give some more code example. Can you create fiddle that imitate incorrect behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced blur event with keypress event and check for enter key is pressed or not like below:

```
.keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                //write code
            }
        });
```

Now its working without page reloading. I have replaced blur with keypress, because blur not called when enter key pressed in chrome.

And thanks all for your helpful suggetions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like:

```
if((e.keyCode == 13) {// do something;
return false;}
```

*e.keyCode == 13* will help You to check is Enter is pressed, and then You can do some of Yours code, after that You have to return false to prevent browser from sending data

Comment: I have changed my code as per you solution.But still not working.

Comment: Yes I' ve edited Your post, You should put e variable in `self.DisablePostBack = function (e) {`. If not there will be error e is undefined;

Comment: When do You use the code
 `self.DisablePostBack = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    }
};`
You should use it in the focus function. And You should do something if the key code is difrent than 13 (ie return true);

Comment: I have tried it in focus, but still page reloading occures when pressing enter key.

Comment: Can You give me the link? It will be easer. If its locally You can put the code to: http://jsfiddle.net/